# Image Loading in c# from a web URL

Tags: c#

am trying to display an image in a "toolStrip" i c# from a weburl. Am using the following methode to get the image

```
WebRequest requestPic5 = WebRequest.Create(icon_path);
                         requestPic5.Timeout = 5000;
                         WebResponse responsePic5 = null;
                         Image Myimg5 = null;

if (requestPic5 != null)
   {
      responsePic5 = requestPic5.GetResponse();
      if (responsePic5 != null)
         {
            Myimg5 = Image.FromStream(responsePic5.GetResponseStream());
          }
   }
```

its failing when  `Myimg5 = Image.FromStream(responsePic5.GetResponseStream());` throws an exception but the image is still there in the url

But unfortunately most of the time its not loading properly and sometimes throwing a 404 error

Comment: What do the raw contents of the stream look like?  Are they decorated in HTML or something?

Comment: Thanks Jacob ,
the data i need to stream is a png image file.

Comment: I was thinking that you could output the stream to the debug window and see if there were tags around your image bytes.  But, I just tested it and everything worked fine for me.  Are you sure that the image is available to you via a webrequest?  Can you try this image?  http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png  (the stackoverflow logo) and see if things work?

Comment: yes jacob , it will work some time and not at  some time....
but at any time if it fails the entire process will be halted.....

Can you please suggest any other alternative to load am image from a web url which can for work faster

Answer (score 6):

The response stream has other stuff that you don't necessarily want.  You really just want the raw data of the imgage file, so you can use:

`new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData("http://address/file.ico"));`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the website is protected against hot linking. Since images are large in size in compare to html pages and websites pays for their used bandwidth, this is a mechanism for protecting websites from bsndwidth theft, by other websites.

The idea is using some kind of authentication and make sure a real user is asking for the image. This is usually done by cookies on the page which contains the image. You need to get those cookies and send them with your request. You need to add a `CookieContainer` to your request, then request the page the image resides and at the end retrieve the image (use the same request for all steps, cookies would be added and used automatically).