# Load image in c# windows application

Tags: c#

please suggest any method to  load am image from a web url which can work faster in a c# windows application  other than webRequest class

Comment: What's wrong with WebRequest?

Comment: That might be a bit of premature optimisation; the latency to the remote server is going to be the deciding factor in performance here -  whilst tweaking the code can have a little effect, it might be useful to explain why you think it's worth writing your own `WebRequest`

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509653/image-loading-in-c-from-a-web-url

Answer (score 5):

[system.net.webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Of course, it's not really *faster* from a performance standpoint.  If you're loading the image from the web, *nothing* will save you from having to send an http request to download it (you might try caching the image locally so at least you only need to download it once).

But it is faster in the sense of development time.

Comment: Webclient is just a wrapper around HttpWebRequest. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596156688/httpwebrequest

Comment: @ebpower: indeed.  But that doesn't change that it's easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about how long it takes to retrieve an image from the web, you could always cache it and update it in the background. It won't help the first time, but will make the app seem faster on subsequent loads.